# Passing of function's parameters by reference problems

Tags: python, list, function, parameter-passing

In the code below, I’m trying to change Python list inside functions through passing it by reference.

```
def ListInitialization(aList):
    aList = list(range(10))
    print("\"ListInitialization\" aList print: ", aList, "\n")

def ListEdit(aList):
    aList[2] = 2222
    print("\"ListEdit\" aList print: ", aList, "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aList = []
    ListInitialization(aList)
    print("\"Main\" after \"ListInitialization\" aList print: ", aList, "\n")
    aList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    ListEdit(aList)
    print("\"Main\" after \"ListEdit\" aList print: ", aList, "\n")
```

The output of the above code is:

```
“ListInitialization” aList print: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
“Main” after “ListInitialization” aList print: []
“ListEdit” aList print: [0, 1, 2222, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
“Main” after “ListEdit” aList print: [0, 1, 2222, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why didn’t the `ListInitialization` function changes to `aList` go beyond the `ListInitialization` function? But the `ListEdit` function changes made to `aList` remained after the `ListEdit` was completed?

Comment: Python **does not support call by reference semantics**. Ever. For that matter, it doesn't support call by value either.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html; assignments to a name have no affect on the previous value of that name.

Comment: In `ListInitialization` you actually create a new list and assign it to local variable `aList`. If you really wanted to achieve passing-by-reference behavior here, you should replace range like `aList[:] = list(range(10))`. But don't do that! Return a list instead and assign the result to a variable outside of function.

Comment: @Tupteq that would **not** give you call by reference behavior. The distinguishing freature of call by reference here is that *assignments to the parameter are visible in the caller*. So, suppose Python *did* have call by reference. You could do something like `def func(&a): a = 0` then `b = 42; func(b); print(b)` would print 0, but you *cannot do this in Python*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Excuse me, but what are the benefits for python users from this approach in passing function parameters?

Comment: @Vitalii I'm not sure what you mean. It's a pretty standard evaluation strategy, used by Java, Python, Ruby, Javascript, Scheme.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: "For that matter, it doesn't support call by value either." As you said, the passing semantics is identical to Java, and it's called pass-by-value in Java, both here on StackOverflow and elsewhere on the Internet.